# Daily Unlock in LibGDX

Tags: java, libgdx

I am trying to make a game that is a collection of mini games. The mini games will unlock daily. There are story for each day. And the story cannot be repeated so for example the player start playing the game on Monday. He/she will unlock the story for day one and the first mini game. To unlock the next story he/she must wait until the next day. If the player skip playing at Tuesday and resume at Wednesday then he/she will lose the second story and the second mini game. My question is how to get current time that is not taken from android settings to prevent cheating? I want to prevent the player from cheating by changing android time from settings.

Comment: What did you try so far? The standard `Date` class should be good enough for this, no?

Answer (score 1):

> My question is how to get current time that is not taken from android settings to prevent cheating? I want to prevent the player from cheating by changing android time from settings.

I see only one workaround, get a timestamp from the internet. Here for example : **http://currentmillis.com/api/millis-since-unix-epoch.php**

Of course that would force your players to turn-on mobile data or wi-fi, what would be only meaningful for an online game. Blocking the access to the game if there is no internet available would solve the cheating problem then, but will eventually frustrate players if it supposed to be offline play.

Comment: This is no good, anyway. You can easily spoof the timestamp by simply adding some host rules and returning a timestamp you want.